# unable fire an event for dynamically created component

Tags: delphi

I have created a dynamic TClientDataSet component and tried to fire the OnCalcFields event....it has'nt worked. The code looks like this...

```
 table := TClientDataset.Create(Application);
  table.OnCalcFields := tableCalcFields; //where 'tablecalcfields' is the method defined by me.
  table.FieldDefs := Query1.FieldDefs;
  table.CreateDataSet;
  table.Open;
  Query1.First;
  while not Query1.Eof do
  begin
    table.Append;
    for I := 0 to Query1.FieldList.Count - 1 do
    begin
      table.FieldValues[table.FieldList[i].DisplayName] :=
                  Query1.FieldValues[Query1.FieldList[i].DisplayName];
    end;
    Query1.next;
    table.Post;
  end;
  DataSource2.DataSet := table;
  table.First;
```

after this i will edit the information on the dbgrid(datasource2 is setted to it), at this time the event must fire (if you have a design time component it will)

thanks for answers,
Vijay

Comment: Is that all you do? OnCalcFields won't be fired until you actually position the dataset on a record in the table...

Comment: sorry for the less code, i edited my post.

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but it seems strange to me creating the dataset with owner Application. Normally this would be a form or datamodule.

Comment: Which are the calculated TFields? It looks the table has only plain fields, those got from the TQuery.

Comment: Sorry guys, its my mistake,i don't have calculated fields....
:P sorry sorry

Comment: Uwe Raabe, its just a moke application to say that we can work with cds with out a provider, the real application is yet start and this concept is very imp. in that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't have calculated fields.